# How can i add webview in my class? [findViewById(int) in fragment]

Tags: java, android, android-activity, webview

I have an activity and i want it to display a website using webview. But i am not able to do it with my existing code.

(EDIT: I made the necessary changes as told by Nirmal Raj but now i am getting an error that "Cannot resolve method findViewById(int)" i have edited my code please look at it and identify the problem.)

BlogAcitivity.java

```
package thenerdimite.nuttybuddies;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class BlogActivity extends Fragment {

    View myView;
    WebView webView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_blog, container, false);
        return myView;

        webView = (WebView)myView.findViewById(R.id.blogview);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.blogview);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

}
```

The error "Cannot resolve method findViewById(int)" coming with a red color. What changes should i do in this code so that the webview can work.
Thanks!

Comment: `I am not able to add any public class or something with this code` explain more! what do you mean? and where is the `WebView` I don't see any `WebViews` in you code!

Comment: @AtefHares i didn't add any webview. I tried but got error so i posted the code without webview

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want but I will give you a sample of how to implement a webview.

Layout:

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webs"/>
```

Add this to the layout in which you want to show the `WebView`.

Java Code:

```
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webs);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Since you are using fragments the only difference will be in `findViewById()` function. You have to call `myView.findViewbyId()`.

Also don't forget to add this to the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: I edited my code in question can u take a look at it is now telling that  "Cannot resolve method findViewById(int)"

Comment: place the `return` statement at the end. `return` should be the statement before the closing brace. @Bhavesh

Comment: What is the problem you are having @Bhavesh ? Post your error log or a screenshot of the output.